# Problems publishing ASP.NET Core 5 Web API app in Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-5.0, azure-appservice

I have published my web API

[image: publish]

But I get this error

[image: error]

in Diagnostic Tools I see this but I don't understand it

[image: diagnostic tool]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved

I have not included in the production appsettings.json the parameter used in the CORS configuration (frontendURL)

```
services.AddCors(options=> {
            var frontendURL = Configuration.GetValue<string>("frontend_url");
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder=> {
                builder.WithOrigins(frontendURL).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
            });
        });
```

appsettings.json

```
"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Warning",
  "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
}
},
"ConnectionStrings": {
"BoletusConexion": ".....;"
},
"frontend_url": "http://localhost:4200",
"AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```